# how to get the users/me relation in strapi v4

Tags: javascript, strapi

I added a relation to my user but when I try to query it, I can see it even with the populate deep plug in.

When I add a normal field, there is no problem but the relation is impossible to see.

Here is the user table in the dashboard:

[image: strapi dashboard user table]

Here is the query I'm doing:

http://localhost:1337/api/users/me?populate=deep

end the response I get:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "testAdmin",
  "email": "testadmin@gmail.com",
  "provider": "local",
  "confirmed": true,
  "blocked": false,
  "createdAt": "2023-01-27T20:38:35.624Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-01-28T17:07:51.151Z",
  "test": "test"
}
```

I've seen the same issue in a GitHub repo but it's fair old and I've not seen any updates.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to setup permissions to access `find` on relation contentType

Answer (score 1):

Since the content is related to User Content Type which is controlled by the Users and Permissions plugin, you need to do some extra work.

1. Go to settings
2. Click Roles below the Users and Permissions plugin
3. Click on the role you want to edit.
4. A list of your Content Types will be shown. Scroll and expand the particular Content Type which you related to the User Content Type. In my case, that Content Type is Shipping Address.
5. Select find and save.
6. Make an API request on api/users/me?populate={fieldName} or api/users/me?populate=*

Demonstration of the permission settings.

**Screenshot showing Permission settings for Authenticated role to access Shipping Address Content Type in Strapi:**

[image]

**Screenshot of the API call and response in VScode made with the Rest Client extension:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just try /api/users/me?populate=*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to get the relations, where its nested or not

1. using the generic one
   `api/users/me?populate=*` 
   ** by this you can get the relations, all the field, not nested**
2. by installing strapi-plugin-populate-deep
   `api/users/me?populate=deep,3` 
   ** by this you can get the relations, all the field, but nested(can control with the number mentioning nested levels)**

And all set!